# converting from QString to wstring adding extra escape sequence

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, wstring

I have a QString like

```
QString qReplaceByText("**\\g<char>**");
```

If I try to convert it to a wstring its replacing \ with \\

`std::wstring wReplaceByText = qReplaceByText.toStdWString()`;

qReplaceByText becomes

```
**\\\\g<char>**
```

How can I avoid this ?

This is my code snippet

```
           std::wstring searchText(L"(?P<char>.)(?P=char)");;
            wsregex regExp;
            std::wstring strOut;
            try
            {
                regExp = wsregex::compile( searchText, boost::xpressive::icase );

                std::wstring wsObjectName =  L"tweet" ;

                std::wstring wReplaceByText = qReplaceByText.toStdWString();

                strOut.resize( wsObjectName.length() + wReplaceByText.length() );
                std::wstring::iterator itOut = strOut.begin();
                boost::xpressive::regex_replace(itOut, wsObjectName.begin() , wsObjectName.end(), regExp, wReplaceByText,  regex_constants::format_perl );
            }
```

Comment: The '/' are not replaced, it's just the way to display your wstring. If you print the sizes of your strings, they are equal.

Comment: @RomhaKorev The issue is when I pass this string to boost::regex_replace it does not do a correct replacement and does not recognize \\g<char>

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? (with your regex)

Comment: What is your regex pattern?

Comment: @RomhaKorev (?P<char>.)(?P=char)